# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject after JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public class AdDomainModel
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public AdDomainModel(
            Guid organizationId,
            string domainName,
            string adDomainConfiguration
            )
        {
            AdDomainConfiguration = JObject.Parse(adDomainConfiguration);
            DomainName = domainName;
            OrganizationId = organizationId;
        }

        // Properties

        public Guid OrganizationId
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public String DomainName
        {
            get;
        }

        public JObject AdDomainConfiguration
        {
            get;
        }
    }

private static readonly Guid OrganizationId = Guid.NewGuid();
private static readonly string DomainName = "some.domain";
private static readonly string AdDomainConfiguration = $@"
    {{
        ""preferredDC"":""new.newdomain.name"",
        ""collectEnabledUsersOnly"":""true""
    }}";

[TestMethod]
        public void AdDomainModel_SerializationTest()
        {
var _adDomainModel = new AdDomainModel(
                OrganizationId,
                DomainName,
                AdDomainConfiguration
                );
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_adDomainModel);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdDomainModel>(serialized);

            Assert.AreEqual(_adDomainModel.DomainName, deserialized.DomainName);
            Assert.AreEqual(_adDomainModel.AdDomainConfiguration, deserialized.AdDomainConfiguration);
            Assert.AreEqual(_adDomainModel.OrganizationId, deserialized.OrganizationId);
        }
```

Failing here:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdDomainModel>(serialized);
```

serialized variable during debugging:

{"organizationId":"14ca4438-abff-48cf-9b86-57492217b08e","domainName":"some.domain","adDomainConfiguration":{"preferredDC":"new.newdomain.name","collectEnabledUsersOnly":"true"}}

notice there is no quotation mark after "adDomainConfiguration": and this is cause a problem.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPJ8.png)

adDomainConfiguration is dynamic ie it can have different fields with different types.

I need it as an object not as a String in order to pass it as an object in API response:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAIsl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the code. Since Newtonsoft.Json using a constructor to deserilize json,  adDomainConfiguration input parameter should JObject, not a string

```
[JsonConstructor]
    public AdDomainModel(
        Guid organizationId,
        string domainName,
        JObject adDomainConfiguration
        )
    {
        AdDomainConfiguration = adDomainConfiguration;
        DomainName = domainName;
        OrganizationId = organizationId;
    }
```

and you have to init it this way

```
private static readonly Guid OrganizationId = Guid.NewGuid();
private static readonly string DomainName = "some.domain";
private static readonly string AdDomainConfiguration = @"
{
        ""preferredDC"":""new.newdomain.name"",
        ""collectEnabledUsersOnly"":""true""
}";

var _adDomainModel = new AdDomainModel(OrganizationId, DomainName, 
JObject.Parse(AdDomainConfiguration));
```